# compiler shouts an error with the make file

Tags: c, makefile

After a certain attempt to write a simple program with a main and one function,
I ask for your help to find the bug. I include the 3 files that are in action:

- the main function in `base.c`
- the function in `fun.c`
- the `makefile`

The compiler says that the function is called in a bad way in the main:

```
undefined reference to `fun'
```

**`base.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(char c);

main()
{
    printf("please enter a single char\n");
    char c=getchar();

    fun(c);

    return 0;
}
```

**`fun.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun(char c)
{
    printf("%d3 is the value of your char!\n", 'c');
    return 0;
}
```

**`makefile`**

```
charprint:  base.o fun.o    
    gcc -g -Wall -ansi base.o fun.o -o charprint

base.o:   base.c
     gcc -g -Wall -ansi base.c -o base.o

fun.o:  fun.c
    gcc -g -Wall -ansi fun.c -o fun.o
```

Comment: In the code for `fun()`, your argument to `printf()` should be just `c` and not `'c'`.  You probably also mean `%3d` rather than `%d3` though that 'works'; it just doesn't do what you expect.  Note that you should use an explicit `int main(void) { … }`.

Comment: The compilation problem is that you forgot the `-c` flags in the compiler line for `base.o` and `fun.o`.  Interestingly, the simplest fix would be to delete the two compiler command for the two object files — `make` knows how to compile C files to object files.  You could set `CFLAGS += -Wall` (or `CFLAGS = -Wall`) to get the (very important) `-Wall` flag included.  Adding `-Werror` too would be good.

Comment: thank you very much! it works now

Comment: Sidenote: ANSI-C is outdated since almost 20 years. Use modern standard C, i.e. C11 resp. 17.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation problem is that you forgot the `-c` flags in the compiler line for `base.o` and `fun.o`.  One obvious simple (but not very good) way to fix that is:

```
charprint:  base.o fun.o    
    gcc -g -Wall -ansi base.o fun.o -o charprint

base.o:   base.c
     gcc -c -g -Wall -ansi base.c -o base.o

fun.o:  fun.c
    gcc -c -g -Wall -ansi fun.c -o fun.o
```

Interestingly, the simplest fix would be to delete the two compiler command for the two object files — make knows how to compile C files to object files. You could set CFLAGS += -Wall (or CFLAGS = -Wall) to get the (very important) -Wall flag included. Adding `-Werror` too would be good.

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -g -std=c11

charprint:  base.o fun.o    
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} base.o fun.o -o $@

base.o:   base.c

fun.o:  fun.c
```

In the code for `fun()`, your argument to `printf()` should be just `c` and not `'c'`. You probably also mean `%3d` rather than `%d3` though that 'works'; it just doesn't do what you expect. Note that you should use an explicit `int main(void) { … }`.  And you should probably create a header `fun.h` containing:

```
extern int fun(char c);
```

and `#include "fun.h"` in both source files, and add `fun.h` after the source file name in the dependency lines in the makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -Wall -Werror -g -std=c11

charprint:  base.o fun.o    
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} base.o fun.o -o $@

base.o: base.c fun.h

fun.o: fun.c fun.h
```

In fact, you don't need to list the source files as dependencies for the object files; `make` will infer that dependency automatically.  But you do need to specify the header file dependency.

Comment: isn't ${CC} should be defined in Makefile?

Comment: `make` comes equipped with a lot of predefined macros, such as `CFLAGS` and `CC`.  You can see which ones are built in with `make -p -f /dev/null`, for example.